# Finger Lakes and Wineries

Tags: recommendations

Besides beautiful scenery, I heard the [Finger Lakes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_Lakes) region in New York state has some good wineries.

I did some research and found some good resources about the region.

- http://www.fingerlakeswineries.org/
- http://www.fingerlakeswinetours.com/

There are so many routes and so many wineries on each route to chose from, it is overwhelming.

Does anyone have recommendations for specific wineries and/or a route for a 3-4 day long weekend over the fourth of July holiday?

Comment: Can you narrow your question? What are you looking for in a tour? The very best wines in the region regardless of location or convenience? For pinot francs or rieslings? Scenic drives? Low cost? A nice tasting experience (staff and facilities)? Starting from Watkins Glen, Skaneateles, Canandaigua, someplace else?

Comment: @Erin - it does sound good.  As choster says tho, the more detail, the better - as you said, the routes and choices are overwhelming. If you can say what you're after, what types you prefer, what scenery, whether or not you care about prices - and if so, what range etc.

Comment: Generally the people that run Stack Exchange want the site to contain objective questions and answers and they from upon recommendations which tend to be subjective. At travel.SE we are not as hardline on this rule, but to achieve that we require your question to focus on something very specific. We are not here to choose for you or make suggestions. Please make your question more specific so we can find the "one right answer".